# appassembler maven plugin doesn't set "execute" permissions on generated script

Tags: linux, unix, maven, appassembler

The [AppAssembler Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin) does a great job of generating distribution for me. One last problem is that the generated Shell script does not have execution permissions so I need to set them manually.

I am on Linux RedHat

Does anybody know of a clean way to set them automatically?

Comment: 2.0.0 sets the +x bit on the generated scripts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do this is to process the file with another maven plugin like `Antrun` or `Assembly` after running `AppAssembler`.

This issue (see link below) has been brought up on the AppAssembler project issue tracker and it was rejected as `Won't Fix`.

Issue: [MAPPASM-54](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAPPASM-54)

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be set in your `assembly.xml`, in the `fileSet` tag:

```
<fileSets>
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/resources/bin</directory>
  <lineEnding>keep</lineEnding>
  <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
  <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>*.bat</include>
    <include>*.sh</include>
  </includes>
  <fileMode>744</fileMode>
</fileSet>
...
```

Comment: Thanks but your answer is about Assembly plugin. Please follow the link in the question, you will see it is about a different plugin.

Comment: This is correct. Let `appassembler` prepare the assembly into a directory and let `maven-asdsembly-plugin` assemble it with a given descriptor. 

1st: https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-migrations/blob/3a7bc1b13584d9f12bd5487066c4093f9d161266/neo4j-migrations-cli/pom.xml#L60-L84

2nd: https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-migrations/blob/3a7bc1b13584d9f12bd5487066c4093f9d161266/neo4j-migrations-cli/pom.xml#L113-L136

Descriptor: https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-migrations/blob/3a7bc1b13584d9f12bd5487066c4093f9d161266/neo4j-migrations-cli/src/main/assembly/assembly-java.xml

Answer (score 0):

Since Maven 3.0.3 all plugins are executed in the order they are in your pom.xml. So setting the executeable flag in a platform independet manner is as easy as using the maven-enforcer-plugin right after your appassembler plugin.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-beanshell</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <evaluateBeanshell>
                  <condition>
                      import java.io.File;

                      print("set executable for file ${basedir}/dist/bin/mql");
                      new File("${basedir}/dist/bin/mql").setExecutable(true,false);                   

                      true;
                  </condition>
                </evaluateBeanshell>
              </rules>
              <fail>false</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>  
      </plugin>
```